# Почему props падает в attr? Vue

Tags: vue.js

```
<ConditionFilters :bF="bottomFilters"  :selectedFilters="selectedFilters" :priceSlider="priceSlider" :floorSlider="floorSlider"/>

props: ['selectedFilters', 'priceSlider', 'floorSlider', 'bF'],
```

[image: Информация Vue плагина]

Comment: потому что в props нет этого поля

Comment: props: ['selectedFilters', 'priceSlider', 'floorSlider', 'bF'],

Comment: это props с компонента ConditionFilters

Comment: если судить по консоли, а не по обрывкам Вашего кода -  то нет. Приведите воспроизводимый пример

Comment: по дефолту, все attrs, в html, отображаются как аттрибуты. Что у Вас там?